# runtime error maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object while deleting a user in Django admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin

On my development server I am trying to delete a user in the admin and I get this error:

```
RuntimeError maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

It used to work very well until a few days ago.
I'm using Django 1.3.1. I tried with various browsers as I read that some are not suitable for the dev server. I do not remember changing anything other than views in the app, nothing related to users. I updated to the latest version of django-social-auth a few days ago. And apart from that I am clueless about what is going on here! Could somebody shed some light?

Comment: Can you post full traceback?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm new to django and django-social-auth and just reading docs. Way be this describes your problem?
(From [here](http://django-social-auth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/miscellaneous.html)):

> Custom User model If defining a custom user model, do not import
>   social_auth from any models.py that would finally import from the
>   models.py that defines your User class or it will make your project
>   fail with a recursive import because social_auth uses get_model() to
>   retrieve your User.